# get count of records every x time interval between two dates return no records

Tags: postgresql

i have a table with the following data

| inspected | rejected | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 423 | 55 | 2021-06-09 13:28:00.115348+03 |
| 121 | 22 | 2021-06-09 13:29:00.115348+03 |
| 342 | 22 | 2021-06-09 13:30:00.115348+03 |
| 546 | 21 | 2021-06-09 13:31:00.115348+03 |
| 122 | 22 | 2021-06-09 13:32:00.115348+03 |
| 312 | 25 | 2021-06-09 13:33:00.115348+03 |
| 1234 | 12 | 2021-06-09 13:34:00.115348+03 |
| 1331 | 63 | 2021-06-09 13:35:00.115348+03 |

I tried the following SQL ( I'm using PostgreSQL ) but it always returning empty records

I need the interval to be changeable and i can get the count of the inspected and rejected rows between two dates.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + INTERVAL '5 minutes' * round((extract('epoch' FROM created_at) / 1800) * 1800)/60 AS clock,inspected , rejected,created_at
FROM public."Mytable"
WHERE created_at > localtimestamp - INTERVAL '1 week'
AND created_at BETWEEN 2021-06-09 13:28:00.115348+03 AND 2021-06-10 13:28:00.115348+03
GROUP BY round(extract('epoch' FROM created_at) / 1800),created_at,inspected , rejected,created_at
order by clock
```

here is a [sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=7b1098addfc6fc8058bce57bf5148a8d)  what i want is to sum the inspected and rejected and show only one of the values of the linespeed column but grouped into changeable interval ( i will change using javascript and in this sample it's 5 min)

| interval | inspected | rejected | linespeed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '2021-06-09 13:35:00.0000+03' | 3242 | 23 | 333 |
| '2021-06-09 13:40:00.0000+03' | 2424 | 33 | 333 |

edit ----

now in the fiddle i could achieve what i want but the interval_alias calculation return a time stamp with timezone offset of +1 hour and i don't know form were it comes( the original created_at column is +3 same as the server timezone)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Could you please go to dbfiddle.uk and choose your PostgreSQL server and construct your table (MyTable) and input your data. Then provide us with your sample data above. **Most** importantly, show us your desired result - I'm having difficulty understanding exactly what it is you want! Put all that information back here - you can put a comment under this with the @ symbol and my handle (no spaces) when you've done this!

Comment: hi @Vérace i updated my post with sample data and requirements.... thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't produced a fiddle - could you please do that? What's `linespeed`? We need clues, otherwise, we're flying blind!

Comment: @Vérace sorry for the inconvenience.. i edited the question and added a fiddle link also added what i need right now as i solved some of my problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found what i want with this sql code :

```
SELECT sum(inspected) as inspected,sum(rejected) as rejected, linespeed
        ,to_timestamp((floor((extract('epoch' from created_at) / 3600 )) * 3600 ))
         as interval_alias
         FROM public."MULTI_M22"
        where created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-09 13:28:00.115348+03' AND '2021-06-09 16:32:00.115348+03'
        GROUP BY interval_alias, linespeed
        order by interval_alias
```

thanks

Comment: Don't forget to mark your own answer as correct - it may help others with similar problems!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the combination of these two conditions:

```
WHERE created_at > localtimestamp - INTERVAL '1 week'
AND created_at BETWEEN 2021-06-09 13:28:00.115348+03 AND 2021-06-10 13:28:00.115348+03
```

The `created_at > localtimestamp - INTERVAL '1 week'` limits results to those in the last week, while the `BETWEEN` filter only permits timestamps on 2021-06-09 & 10. Since 2021-06-10 is now well over a week in the past, there are  no dates that satisfy both conditions, and you will never get results.

Guessing a bit as to your requirements, but I assume that when you have a `created_at between (a, b)` clause, you should remove the `created_at > localtimestamp - INTERVAL '1 week'` one.